# -bash: slather: command not found

Tags: xcode, slather

Slather command not found error after successful installation. I have updated the commands used in Terminal. Can anyone help to identify the missing flags or setting?

```
MacBook-Pro-5:DemoAPP mackbook$ gem install slather
Successfully installed slather-2.7.2
Parsing documentation for slather-2.7.2
Done installing documentation for slather after 0 seconds
1 gem installed


MacBook-Pro-5:DemoAPP mackbook$ slather
**-bash: slather: command not found**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2392293/6309), check your `gem environment`, `gem env` and your `$PATH`

Look for the executable slather in one of the [gem paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4233776/6309), and make sure the full path is referenced in your current `$PATH`.

Comment: @GobiM , can you please explain more  with example, how it works. Thanks.